# Codeigniter htaccess issue with wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, codeigniter

I am facing an issue, although there are many answers to it but none seems to work.

I have a hosting where wordpress is installed.
Within there I created a folder and installed codeigniter.
Somehow I have managed to remove index.php from url, but the css & other files within iscaffold are not working.

Here are the .htaccess files.

Root:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L] 
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Subfolder:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /lastwish
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

The url:
http://epf-india.co.in.md-in-23.webhostbox.net/lastwish/login

You can view source and see the css & js files are redirecting.

Thanks

Comment: Try to change `RewriteBase /lastwish/`with final `/`

Comment: Doing that redirects it to main site: http://epf-india.co.in/

Answer (score 0):

add  in header css link.
like

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url();?>iscaffold/backend_skins/stylesheets/themes/default/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

Comment: Issue is something else, files are not accessible by direct path

Answer (score 0):

1) wordpress `.htaccess`

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
    </IfModule>
```

2) Codeigniter `.htaccess`

```
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

3) And Changed in your config file i.e `codeigniter/application/config/config.php`

```
        $config['base_url'] = '/codeigniter';
        $config['index_page'] = '';
```

4) you css link is like - create folder in /codeigniter root assets
                   codeigniter
                   -application
                   -assets
                   -system
                   -user_guide

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/iscaffold/backend_skins/stylesheets/themes/default/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

you will try this.